# iphone dev sending post to Linkedin from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linkedin-api

i want to post on linkedin from my iphone app, can anyone guide me with some sort of tutorial urls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Linkedin API](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest)
And at [RestKit](http://restkit.org/)

Combine the two and you are good to know. If you take a tutorial on restKit and replace the example links with linkedin api links you already have what you need.